# cannot Install Cordova Application in the Android Phone

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova for building an android application. so, When I built the `apk file` with `cordova build android --release` command, and copy that into the Android phone due to installing, unfortunately the application could not be installed and bellow `error` is appear :

`Instalation failed.`

my phone android `version` is 4.4.2

the application target is 15.

Thanks of everybody to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign your application first. You have to use the `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk` and follow the [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) howto of the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks I follow your answer and create `keystore` and `ant.properties`, but My problem is not resolved yet :( The name of the output Application : android-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: Normally once signed, the APK name should become android-release.apk. If you don't have that, it does mean you didn't finish the process.

Comment: Moreover, you can directly integrate that into Cordova now : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_tools.md.html#Android%20Shell%20Tool%20Guide ("Signing the App" part).

Comment: I build unsigned apk first and then via `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name` command resolve this problem. Thanks a lot @Ivan Gabriele.